# WSO2 GReg 5.1.0 - Searching using a Query with API does not work

Tags: java, wso2

I'm trying to search for governance artifacts by using the **GovernanceUtils** class and calling the method `findGovernanceArtifacts(String query, Registry registry, String mediaType)` as proposed by the documentation ['Searching using a Query'](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Searching+using+a+Query).

When I do so I will get a NullPointerException with the following stack trace.
The same happens if I use any of the other proposed method invocations on the **GovernanceArtifactManager** or **GenericArtifactManager** .

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.AuthorizationKey.checkAttributesAreEqual(AuthorizationKey.java:117)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.AuthorizationKey.equals(AuthorizationKey.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1023)
    at org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheImpl.containsKey(CacheImpl.java:256)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.AuthorizationCache.isUserAuthorized(AuthorizationCache.java:150)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.isUserAuthorized(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:160)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.realm.RegistryAuthorizationManager.isUserAuthorized(RegistryAuthorizationManager.java:195)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.service.ContentBasedSearchService.isAuthorized(ContentBasedSearchService.java:297)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.service.ContentBasedSearchService.searchContentInternal(ContentBasedSearchService.java:257)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.service.ContentBasedSearchService.searchByAttribute(ContentBasedSearchService.java:279)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.internal.IndexingServiceComponent$AttributeSearchServiceImpl.search(IndexingServiceComponent.java:164)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.internal.IndexingServiceComponent$AttributeSearchServiceImpl.search(IndexingServiceComponent.java:158)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the Governance Artifacts first?

*GovernanceUtils.loadGovernanceArtifacts((UserRegistry) gov);*

Please see a sample implementation here https://github.com/wso2/product-greg/blob/master/modules/samples/ws-client/src/org/wso2/carbon/registry/ws/client/sample/SampleWSRegistrySearchClient.java